# Why is sizeof(type) the size of a pointer, not the size of the type itself?

Tags: c, sizeof

In this code, why is `sizeof(x)` the size of a pointer, not the size of the type `x`?

```
typedef struct {
  ...
} x;

void foo() {
  x *x = malloc(sizeof(x));
}
```

Comment: your question has nothing to do with `malloc`. With a bit of sanity your question is "what is `x`?"

Comment: @JensGustedt: Well, yes - however, isn't `sizeof` *mostly* used together with `malloc`?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `sizeof` either. As I said your question is "what is `x`?" or even more clearer "which of the two `x` to I get here, the type or the pointer variable?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because C says:

> (C99, 6.2.1p7) "Any other identifier has scope that begins just    after the completion of its declarator."

So in your example, the scope of the object `x` start right after the `x *x`:

```
x *x = /* scope of object x starts here */
       malloc(sizeof(x));
```

To convince yourself, put another object declaration of type `x` right after the declaration of the object `x`: you will get a compilation error:

```
void foo(void)
{
    x *x = malloc(sizeof(x));  // OK
    x *a;   // Error, x is now the name of an object
}
```

Otherwise, as  Shahbaz notee in the comments of another answer, this is still not a correct use of `malloc`. You should call `malloc` like this:

```
T *a = malloc(sizeof *a);
```

and not

```
T *a = malloc(sizeof a);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because `sizeof(x)` uses the innermost definition of `x`, which is the pointer. To avoid this problem, don't use the same name for a type and a variable.

Comment: Also, with malloc, use it like this: `type *var = malloc(sizeof(*var));` instead of `malloc(sizeof(type))`

Comment: The reason for Shahbaz recommendation is that it means that the type of `var` can change and your code will still be correct. If you use `type` instead of `var*` then you have to remember to change `type` in the declaration and within `sizeof`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to not give different things different names (not only in programming):

The academic reason for the behavior observer had already been mentioned by my dear fellow annotators.

To give clear advises name diffenet things differnet (here: variable types and variable instances):

```
typedef struct {
  ...
} X;

void foo() {
  X *x = malloc(sizeof(X));
}
```

An even more flexible way to code this example would be (as also already mentioned by Shahbaz's comment):

```
typedef struct {
  ...
} X;

void foo() {
  X *x = malloc(sizeof(*x));
}
```

The latter example allows you to change the type of `x` without changing the code doing the allocation.

The drawback of this approach is that you could switch from using references to arrays and verse vica (as type for `x`) without being notified by the compiler, and break your code doing so.